# Getting the foreground window when a hotkey is pressed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to get the active window when a certain hotkey is pressed however my program is always returning the main form of my application as the active window, not whatever is currently up on the screen (Firefox, Chrome, etc.). I suspect that once I pressed the hotkey the form is somehow considered active and that's why it's being returned as the foreground window?

This is what I'm using to get the currently active window

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

public IntPtr getCurrentlyActiveWindow()
{
    //Debugging
    const int nChars = 256;
    IntPtr handle = IntPtr.Zero;
    StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(nChars);
    handle = GetForegroundWindow();
    GetWindowText(handle, Buff, nChars);
    MessageBox.Show(Buff.ToString());

    return GetForegroundWindow();
}
```

Any ideas on what I can do to get the ACTUAL active window?

Comment: Adding `this.Visible = false;` right before the return statement seems to make it behave correctly, but is this a good way to go about solving this issue?

Comment: You will definitely need to explain how you get your getCurrentlyActiveWindow() to run, decent odds that this has something to do with the problem.  Calling GetForegroundWindow() again after displaying the MessageBox is also unwise.

Comment: Yeah I realized the issue with the message box right after I posted this, I was just doing that as a little test, I'll update the post with more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got everything sorted out, I was accidentally giving focus to my form before I get the currently active window. This is what I ended up with

```
//Listen for the hotkey
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    base.WndProc(ref m);

    if (m.Msg == WM_HOTKEY)
    {
        Keys vk = (Keys)(((int)m.LParam >> 16) & 0xFFFF);
        int fsModifiers = ((int)m.LParam & 0xFFFF);

        //Perform action when hotkey is pressed
        if (vk == userHotkey)
        {
            minimizeWindow();
        }
    }
}

//Minimize the currently active window
private void minimizeWindow()
{
    //Get a pointer to the currently active window
    IntPtr hWnd = getCurrentlyActiveWindow();
    if (!hWnd.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
    {
        //Minimize the window
        ShowWindowAsync(hWnd, SW_SHOWMINIMIZED);
    }
}

//Get the currently active window
private IntPtr getCurrentlyActiveWindow()
{
    this.Visible = false;
    return GetForegroundWindow();
}
```